# How to use solutions created by sympy's linear equation solver

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am using sympy to solve a system of linear equations and I want to use one of the solutions in further calculation. First, I wanted to pull a specific solution from the generated dictionary for my system of linear equations. I tried **dict['key']** as I believe you would normally but it does work. Below is the code I tried to run.

```
from sympy import symbols, solve

m2,x2a,x2b,x2c,m3,m4,m5,x5a,x5b,x5c = 
symbols('m2,x2a,x2b,x2c,m3,m4,m5,x5a,x5b,x5c')
solution = solve((100-m2-m3,
              .980*m3-.96*(.450*100),
              100*.300-m2*x2a,
              1-x2a-x2b-x2c,
              x2c*m2-.04*(.450*100),
              m2-m4-m5,
              m2*x2b-m4*.06-m5*x5b,
              .940*m4-.97*(x2a*m2),
              m5*x5a-.03*(x2a*m2),
              1-x5a-x5b-x5c),
            [m2,x2a,x2b,x2c,m3,m4,m5,x5a,x5b,x5c], dict=True)
print(solution[0]['m2'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkDP2.png)

Comment: Please post code as text. It helps us reproduce your situation quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there can be more than one solution to an equation or system of equations.
That is why `sym.solve` returns a list of dicts, not just a dict.

Notice that `print(solution)` begins with a bracket (indicating a list):

```
[{m2: ...}]
```

Therefore, to access the value of `m2` for the first (and in this case only) solution, you would use

```
solution[0][m2]
```

In general, to loop through all solutions, you could use:

```
for s in solution:
    print(s[m2])
```

Notice also that the dict uses SymPy Symbols as keys, not strings.

If you ever run into a similar problem again, you can investigate the problem by inspecting the `.keys` attribute:

```
In [190]: list(solution[0].keys())
Out[190]: [m2, x2a, x2b, x2c, m3, m4, m5, x5a, x5b, x5c]
```

If the keys were strings, you would have seen `['m2', 'x2a', 'x2b', 'x2c', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'x5a', 'x5b', 'x5c']`.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the updated code and ran it. However, I'm getting key errors even though "m2" should be in my dictionary.

Comment: Ah, the dictionary uses SymPy Symbols as keys. So use `solution[0][m2]` instead of `solution[0]['m2']`.